# PHP-How to choose XML section based on an attribute?

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework

All,

I have a config xml file in the following format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configdata>
    <development>
        <siteTitle>You are doing Development</siteTitle>
    </development>
    <test extends="development">
        <siteTitle>You are doing Testing</siteTitle>
    </test>
    <production extends="development">
        <siteTitle>You are in Production</siteTitle>
    </production>
</configdata>
```

To read this config file to apply environment settings, currently I am using, the following code in index.php file:

```
$appEnvironment = "production";
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml('/config/settings.xml', $appEnvironment );
```

To deploy this code on multiple environments, as user has to change index.php file. Instead of doing that, is it possible to maintain an attribute in the xml file, "say active=true". Based on which the Zend_Config_Xml will know which section of the xml file settings to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Zend Framework, I highly suggest you just use the APPLICATION_ENV constant that's defined in Zend Application's default index.php. If you're not, you could probably do this regardless.

```
// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
```

It corresponds to your the environmental variable set in your site's `.htaccess` file:

```
//.htaccess
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
```

You could then load your config file like so:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml('/config/settings.xml', APPLICATION_ENV );
```

Then to switch environments, all that needs to be done is switch the value in the .htaccess file. On my server, I have my deployment script set up to automatically switch the value based on which environment I'm deploying to:

```
$ sed -i 's/development/production/' /path/to/site/root/.htaccess
```

Answer (score 1):

You could, instead, have a unique bootstrap file for development and a unique bootstrap file for production.

- index.php.production
- index.php.development

These two files can be under source control. A deployment script would copy the appropriate bootstrap to index.php and away you go. The index.php file can, and should, be ignored by source control - otherwise you are just stepping on toes.

Of course, the specialized bootstrap files would contain the appropriate environment string.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to handle this, probably the easiest would be [setting the application environment constant in your vhost file](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html#learning.quickstart.create-project.vhost).

If you don't have access to the vhost file (shared hosting, for example), you can place a separate config file in a location on the server that's available in all environments.

You might place server.xml in /home/username (pick a directory that's available in all of your environments).

server.xml might look like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configdata>
    <properties>
        <environment>production</environment>
    </properties>
</configdata>
```

Load server.xml as you would any other config file

```
$server = new Zend_Config_Xml('/home/username/server.xml', 'properties');
```

Finally, you can load your config file across multiple environments without having to edit anything in your application.

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml('/config/settings.xml', $server->environment );
```

The one gotcha here is you must ensure your server.xml files are in place before deploying your app.